# How easy to call external Web APIs in Meteor?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, meteor

Does (or will) Meteor provide a library to handle external Web API calls? E.g. to build a Meteor app that integrates with Facebook Graph API or Google Spreadsheet API.

Answer (score 20):

Meteor now includes the http package.  First, run `meteor add http`.  Then you can make HTTP requests on the server in either sync or async style:

```
// server sync
res = Meteor.http.get(SOME_URL);
console.log(res.statusCode, res.data);

// server async
Meteor.http.get(SOME_URL, function (err, res) {
  console.log(res.statusCode, res.data);
});
```

Same thing works on the client, but you have to use the async form.

Comment: Newbie Q - is the synchronous style blocking? Eg. all other incoming requests must wait on a response from SOME_URL?

Comment: Not to discount your question... it's a good one. I think a deeper question I have for @debergalis is whether the async `Meteor.http.get` breaks out of a fiber or whether it spawns off its own fiber. :) Now, that would be super interesting to understand - and would help understand some higher level abstractions and philosophy of meteor!

Answer (score 3):

```
if (Meteor.is_server) {
    var http = __meteor_bootstrap__.require("http")
    // talk to external HTTP API like you would in node.js
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to call external HTTP API in browser via XHR?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP

HTTP provides an HTTP request API on the client and server. To use these functions, add the HTTP package to your project with $ meteor add http.